# Pygame not displaying text

Tags: python, pygame

I have this bit of code in my main() function that is meant to show a countdown timer for my game but it is not displaying the time left text. I've run the game and the countdown timer code works fine but there is no text for it. Please help.

```
    def main():
        rand = random.randint(1, 4)
        frame_count = 0
        frame_rate = 60
        start_time = 60
        running = True
        while running:
            total_seconds = start_time - (frame_count // frame_rate)
            minutes = total_seconds // 60
            seconds = total_seconds % 60
            output_string = "Time left: {0:02}:{1:02}".format(minutes, seconds)
            screen.blit(font.render(output_string, True, WHITE), (150, 110))
            frame_count += 1
            clock.tick(frame_rate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to colour the screen before drawing the text. like this:

```
screen.fill(BLACK)
```

then you draw the text:

```
screen.blit(font.render(output_string, True, WHITE), (150, 110))
```

then to display everything you must write:

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

at the end it should look like this:

```
def main():
    rand = random.randint(1, 4)
    frame_count = 0
    frame_rate = 60
    start_time = 60
    running = True
    while running:
        total_seconds = start_time - (frame_count // frame_rate)
        minutes = total_seconds // 60
        seconds = total_seconds % 60
        output_string = "Time left: {0:02}:{1:02}".format(minutes, seconds)

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        screen.blit(font.render(output_string, True, WHITE), (150, 110))
        pygame.display.flip()

        frame_count += 1
        clock.tick(frame_rate)
```